# UnitTest ResourceFilter - IAsyncResourceFilter with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-mvc, moq

I have a simple resource filter which I need to write a test for
as it implements `IAsyncResourceFilter`, the only method I have is

```
public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
```

I cannot workout how to mock these parameters
I need to be able to set some `RouteData` values on the ResourceExecutingContext and test that the `ResourceExecutionDelegate` has been called.

I have tried setting up the ResourceExecutingContext using a mocked HttpContext and `ActionContext` with some mocked `IFilterMetadata` and `IValueProviderFactory`'s

but am struggling with what to do with the `ResourceExecutionDelegate`

can anyone point me in the right direction please

Comment: Check their repo on Github and I am certain you will find out how they tested it.

Comment: to find the tests? I can find the interface definition, but thats not much help..

Comment: They will have tests for any of their classes that derive from that interface. They usually do

Answer (score 1):

one solution is without mocking -

```
  var httpClient = new HttpClient();
  var filter = new YourAsyncResourceFilter(httpClient);
  var actionContext = new ActionContext(
    new DefaultHttpContext(),
    new RouteData(),
    new ActionDescriptor()
    );
  var filters = new List<IFilterMetadata>();
  var values = new List<IValueProviderFactory>();
  var nextContext = new ResourceExecutedContext(actionContext, filters);

  var context = new ResourceExecutingContext(actionContext, filters, values);
  var next = new ResourceExecutionDelegate(() => Task.FromResult(nextContext));

  //Run
  await filter.OnResourceExecutionAsync(context, next);
```

also, regarding `ResourceExecutionDelegate`, you can also just mock it directly and pass it

```
// instead of the "next" variablt use the following 
var nextMock = new Mock<ResourceExecutionDelegate>();
//Run
await filter.OnResourceExecutionAsync(context, nextMock.Object);
```

tested with dot net core 2.1

Comment: httpClient? In WebhookVerifySignatureFilter ctor has: IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory